# Sometime ERROR copy file from bundle to documents directory in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy

I am trying to copy a file from my bundle to the documents directory in iOS with the following code.

code:

```
- (NSString*)getModuleHome{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[[paths  objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"webapp" ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"modules"];
    return path;
}

- (void)FirstLoad{
    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self getModuleHome]]) {
        //建立目录
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[self getModuleHome] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BLYLogInfo(@"FirstLoad");
    NSString *zipPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@""  ofType:@"zip"];
    NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"modules.zip"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
        BLYLogInfo(@"fileExistsAtPath dataPath");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dataPath error:&error];
    }
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:zipPath toPath:dataPath error:&error])
    {
      BLYLogError(@"Error copying files: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      [Bugly reportError:error];
    }


    BLYLogInfo(@"FirstLoad Unzip");
    NSString *unZipPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"modules"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:unZipPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:unZipPath error:&error];
    }
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:dataPath toDestination:unZipPath];


    BLYLogInfo(@"FirstLoad Copy");
    NSString *destinationPath = [self getModuleHome];
    BLYLogInfo(@"FirstLoad destinationPath:%@",destinationPath);

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        BLYLogWarn(@"FirstLoad removeItemAtPath");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:destinationPath error:&error];
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:unZipPath toPath:destinationPath error:&error]) {
        BLYLogError(@"FirstLoad Error copying files: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [Bugly reportError:error];
        NSLog(@"FirstLoad Clean");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dataPath error:nil];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:unZipPath error:nil];
        //加载出错
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView* view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"提示"
                    message:@"抱歉，资源加载失败，请关闭重试"
                    delegate:self
                    cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [view show];
       });                                                                      
    }
    else{
        BLYLogInfo(@"FirstLoad Clean");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dataPath error:nil];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:unZipPath error:nil];
        [userDef setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"UpdateFlag"];
        [userDef synchronize];
        [self FirstReload];
    }      
}
```

Attach Log:

> User Data:    NSErrorUserInfo: {  NSDestinationFilePath =
>   "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3575F3DD-4DC7-4472-A3D0-D4FF86C40BEF/Documents/webapp/modules/ihub/img/cat.png";
>     NSFilePath =
>   "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3575F3DD-4DC7-4472-A3D0-D4FF86C40BEF/tmp/modules/ihub/img/cat.png";
>     NSSourceFilePathErrorKey =
>   "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3575F3DD-4DC7-4472-A3D0-D4FF86C40BEF/tmp/modules/ihub/img/cat.png";
>     NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"No such
>   file or directory\"";     NSUserStringVariant = (     Copy    );  }

The app has been released.
Most phones are normal.
Only some phones have this problem.
Each log file reported errors is not the same file not exist.

SAMPLE:

> NSError(NSCocoaErrorDomain:4)The
>   file“contractpayment-detail.html”doesn’t exist。
>   NSError(NSCocoaErrorDomain:4)The file “vacating.png” doesn’t exist.
>   NSError(NSCocoaErrorDomain:4)The file “Mode.ts” doesn’t exist.
>   NSError(NSCocoaErrorDomain:4)The file “SystemCtrl.js” doesn’t exist.

"Why? How to fix it？"

Comment: pathForResource @"" What that mean?

Comment: find all zip file。No name specified

Comment: it not Return all Zip File name. you have to sapicify the name of file.

Comment: i can give you an example where i am copying the images from main bundle to  to documents directory .

Comment: Do you mean specify a name？

Comment: But the error place not here.
My purpose is to find a zip file, unzip it to the tmp directory, then transfer the directory to the sandbox.
Error here.
![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:unZipPath toPath:destinationPath error:&error]

Comment: do you have one or more than one zip file. can you show the zipPath value?

Comment: only one.
"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2BB90F1D-E767-456B-8F9B-D76DC3D8666F/OA_App.app/modules.zip"

Comment: plz remove the file from main bundle and copy it again. this code works.     NSString *zipPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@""  ofType:@"zip"];
     NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Hostng_Details_Format.zip"];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    {
        // copy it over
   
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:zipPath toPath:dataPath error:&error];
    }

Answer (score 0):

plz try this code

```
 //array of main bundle images
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"admin_1454993109_restaurants_uploaded",
                                 @"admin_1454993149_other_uploaded",
                                 @"admin_1454993170_car_uploaded",
                                 @"admin_1454993206_home_uploaded",
                                 @"admin_1454993235_fashion_uploaded",
                                 @"admin_1454993290_shirt_uploaded",
                                @"admin_1454993347_electronic_uploaded",
                                 @"admin_1454993380_notes_uploaded", nil];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {


            // file URL in our bundle
            NSURL *fileFromBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]] withExtension:@"jpg"];

            // Destination URL

            NSString *path = [self MyImagesDocumentsDirectoryPath];

            NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",path,[array objectAtIndex:i]];

            NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

            NSError *error;

            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
            {
                // copy it over
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtURL:fileFromBundle toURL:destinationURL error:&error];
                NSLog(@"%@",error);

            }


        }

- (NSString *)MyImagesDocumentsDirectoryPath
{
    NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];
    return dataPath;
}
```

here i am copying the images into MyFolder from Main bundle. you can give your zip files name and use this code.